# d3.js cloud from external .csv or .txt file?

Tags: javascript, text, csv, d3.js, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud using D3. To do this, I'm modifying Jason Davis' code: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

I want to change the code so that instead of using a word array, I can just link to a .txt or a .csv file with a larger amount of text.

I tried using the d3.text() and d3.csv() methods, but I'm doing something wrong. Since both 
methods call for a URL, I used a data URL generator (http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) to turn a text file into a URL. I then changed the code and inserted the dataurl as follows:

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var text = d3.text(data:text/plain;base64,RGVsbCwgdGhl....continued....more...URLdata)

  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
  .words(text.map(function(d) {
    return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
  }))
  .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
  .font("Impact")
  .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .on("end", draw)
  .start();
```

The second option I tried was to insert the text into a script tag in the html and then reference that in the JS code like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script id="text" type="text/plain">Dell, the company, has...more..text...</script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var text = d3.select("#text");

  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
      .words(text.map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
        }))

etc........
```

Could someone help me figure out a way to read in a .txt or .csv file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
are you able to view this?
http://bl.ocks.org/8bb2b55d2c5cf5667b01

---

One way to become familiar with working d3 and .csv files 
is to review the code samples from [Scott Murray's](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) d3-book on github. 
(Chapter 12 is one place you could review.)
https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/tree/master/chapter_12

Anyway, I've used the us-cities.csv from there in a modified version 
of Jason Davies github example.

Hope this helps.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 CSV</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="cloudlayout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var cityData = [], 
    width = 500, 
    height = 500;

d3.csv("us-cities.csv", function(data) {
    // build the list of city names
    data.forEach( function (d) {
        cityData.push(d.place);
    });

    d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500])
        .words(cityData.map(function(d) {
            return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
        }))
        .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .on("end", draw)
        .start();
});

function draw(words) {
d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}           
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: file Structure]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried rendering the code that you pasted but can't get it to display anything in my browser. I'm new to JS, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong with my script tag? Or something else? This is my code: http://codepad.org/21B1ZJIe  Thank you!

Comment: @user1552159 - Were you able to get the us-cities.csv file and save it to your machine? https://raw.github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_12/us-cities.csv

Comment: Yes, I saved it in the same file as the html file.

Comment: Yes I can. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong then. I've attached a screenshot of my file structure in the original post (with the html file with your code highlighted). Also, the size of the words seem to be generated randomly. Do you know of a word cloud example that generates words whose size stands in proportion to their frequency in the .txt or .csv file? Thanks!